# What is this 87Mb "No description given" update that the software updater manager wants me to install?

Tags: updates

This makes me a bit suspicious:

[image: Img1]
[image]

So I take it either Oracle or Hashicorp have been slack about labeling their updates, or something funny is going on. How can I inspect the contents/signature/something of the update so I can see if it's legitimate without actually installing it?

Comment: Run `apt-get -s upgrade` to see what would be upgraded (and how) without actually performing any real action.

Comment: You can use Synaptic Package Manager to see what packages are being offered up for update.

Comment: @ByteCommander it was `snapd` etc. Thanks.